# Can we alter/add some right click menu item on chrome bookmark bar folder from chrome extenion

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to add custom right click menu item on chrome bookmarks bar folder. Is that possible? How can I achieve such feature?

Comment: This is an internal chrome:// UI, it can't be customized in Chrome.